# Program that removes comments from C and C++ programs

Tags: c, parsing

I have downloaded the latest version of the Linux kernel and I want to perform thorough analysis on it. I want to start by eliminating comments from all the source and header files that belong to it. I am using a code I wrote sometime ago and I want to use it recursively. In the past I tested it on my code and it worked fine, but since I want to use it on a wide scale, I want to know if the code is consistent and successful in all cases.

Can you help me determine if it has bugs that do not deal with removing comments and create mess in certain cases?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int RemoveComments(const char *filename, const char *Output);


int main(void)
{
    RemoveComments("file.cpp", "output.cpp");
    return 0;
}

int RemoveComments(const char *filename, const char *Output)
{
#define NOT_COMMENT (!DOUBLESLASH_Comment && !ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment)

    clock_t t1 = clock();
    FILE *input, *output;
    if (fopen_s(&input, filename, "r"))
    {
        perror(filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (fopen_s(&output, Output, "w"))
    {
        perror(Output);
        exit(1);
    }
    int c, d;

    bool DOUBLESLASH_Comment = 0, ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment = 0, flag = 0;

    int s_QUOTED = 0, d_QUOTED = 0;
    while ((c = getc(input)) != EOF)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case '\\':
        {
            if (NOT_COMMENT)
            {
                if (flag == 1)
                    flag = 0;
                else
                    flag = 1;
            }
        }break;
        case '\'':
        {
            if (NOT_COMMENT && !d_QUOTED)
            {
                if (!flag)
                {
                    s_QUOTED++;
                }
            }
        }break;
        case '"':
        {
            if (NOT_COMMENT && !flag)
            {
                if (!s_QUOTED)
                {
                    d_QUOTED++;
                }
            }
        }break;
        case '/':
        {
            if (NOT_COMMENT && !d_QUOTED)
            {
                if ((d = getc(input)) == '*')
                {
                    ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment = 1;
                }
                else if (d == '/')
                {
                    DOUBLESLASH_Comment = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (d != EOF)
                    {
                        ungetc(d, input);
                    }
                }
            }
        }break;
        case '*':
        {
            if (ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment)
            {
                if ((d = getc(input)) == '/')
                {
                    if ((c = getc(input)) == EOF)
                        return 0;
                    ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (d != EOF)
                    {
                        ungetc(d, input);
                    }
                }
            }
        }break;
        case '\n':
        {
            if (DOUBLESLASH_Comment)
            {
                DOUBLESLASH_Comment = 0;
            }
        }break;
        }
        if (NOT_COMMENT && c != '\\') flag = 0;
        if (d_QUOTED == 2) d_QUOTED = 0;
        if (s_QUOTED == 2) s_QUOTED = 0;
        if (NOT_COMMENT)
        {
            putc(c, output);
        }
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    double elapsed = (double)(t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("time elapsed : %.4f\n", elapsed);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What type of code analysis are you intending to perform? If it is a visual type of analysis then removal of the comments seems counter productive. If it is a machine type of analysis then why not just put the comment exclusion code right into the structure filtering program. If it is any other type of "analysis" then comment stripping for code reuse may be unethical.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I want to perform machine type analysis and I didn't say anything about code reuse.

Comment: You do know that GCC can already do this? The C preprocessor historically was a separate component, and GCC still can emit the result of preprocessing.

Comment: I agree - you don't need to write any code to do this because compilers have already implemented it.

Comment: @MSalters turned that into an answer, should it be community wiki?

Comment: @I'lladdcommentstomorrow: I put it as a comment because it's a meta-answer for CodeReview. It's more of a design review than a code review.

Comment: @machine_1: Talking of design reviews, you probably don't want to do the analysis on the comment-stripped raw source code either. You probably want to work on the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Use all required `#include`s

The program uses the `bool` type and `assert()` but doesn't have the associated required includes.  Fix that by adding this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
```

### Use required `#define`s

As noted in http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen :

> As all bounds-checked functions, fopen_s is only guaranteed to be available if **STDC_LIB_EXT1** is defined by the implementation and if the user defines **STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1** to the integer constant 1 before including .

Because it's an optional part of the C11 standard, it's also non-portable in a strict sense.  For portability, you may wish instead to use the standard `fopen` and do your own error checking instead.

### Think of the user

There are a few user-oriented things I think could be improved.  First, it would probably be better to have the filenames passed in via the command line rather than being hardcoded, and second, it would probably be good to allow the user to specify whether the timing is displayed or not.

### Fix the bug

There is a problem with the parser at the moment.  If we have lines like these:

```
/* comment one *///  comment two
```

the code should remove both comments, but at the moment, it only removes the first one.

### Use better variable names

Variables named `s_QUOTED` and `d_QUOTED` are OK because their names suggest their meanings, but `c`, `d` and `flag` are not good names.

### Consider using named states

It would likely make the code easier to write correctly with named states.  One convenient way to do that is to use an `enum`.

```
enum { INCODE, INQUOTE, INDBLQUOTE, INCOMMENT, GOTSLASH } state = INCODE;
```

### Use one line per declaration

The code currently includes lines like this:

```
bool DOUBLESLASH_Comment = 0, ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment = 0, flag = 0;
```

It makes things a little bit harder to read than if you put them on separate lines like this:

```
bool DOUBLESLASH_Comment = 0;
bool ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment = 0; 
bool flag = 0;
```

Additionally, while it's not strictly incorrect, it helps the reader if the code uses `false` and `true` rather than numeric values for boolean variables.

### Simplify your code

The code currently includes this compound `if` statement:

```
if (flag == 1)
    flag = 0;
else
    flag = 1;
```

This can be simplified:

```
flag = !flag;
```

### Use braces appropriately

In a number of cases, as with the `if` statement mentioned above, curly braces (`{}`) were *not* used, but they *are* used for each `case` statement.  In fact, they're not needed in either case, but I'd recommend using braces for constructs such as `for`, `while` and `if` and omitting them for `case`.

### Return something useful from functions

The `RemoveComments` function is currently written to return `int` but the only value it ever returns is `0`. I'd recommend either returning something useful, such as, for instance a number of comments removed, *or* to change it to a `void` function.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.

Comment: Great advices! However you suggested that there is a problem with the parser. I have tried the example you provided and it didn't remove the relevant part: `int i = 0`, just the comments.

Comment: The difference is line endings.  My machine is a Linux box and you're on a Windows machine.

Comment: Ahh..So it's not a logical error?

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure.  I'll do more testing here to see if I can verify or disprove the theory.

Comment: I've removed that portion of my answer since I can't reproduce it either now (with either line-ending).  Could be that the bug was in my test!  :)

Comment: Just figured it out.  Your code passed that test, but failed a different one so one error was in the code and the other error was in my review!  I've fixed the review now to show the actual error.  Sorry about any confusion my error may have caused!

Comment: "to *change* it to a"?

Comment: putting a `return 0` isn't a bad thing too, it helps not writing stupid bugs when you're returning multiple values from `main()`.

Comment: Regarding `return 0;`: Omitting it is - very strictly seen - a portability issue: `EXIT_SUCCESS` is not guaranteed to be `0`, thus the implicit `return 0;` might mean something different than success on a platform. I don't know of any such platform, though.

Comment: @DanielJour: No, that's incorrect.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188335/why-default-return-value-of-main-is-0-and-not-exit-success?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: In my opinion the `if` for the flag setting looks more clear in it's current form than a cryptic NOT, especially for beginners.

Comment: @Edward Thanks, I learned something today. Back when there was a discussion about that very same topic (I think on this site, could also have been SO) we apparently didn't dig deep enough in the standards.

Comment: @GillBates I disagree.  It is a standard operator and definitely idiomatic.  The if statement is bloated and confusing; if I see an if statement I expect it to do more than just flip the boolean value.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to be pedantic about the C you parse, a newline can actually be escaped with a backslash, continuing the line. Even continuing a `//` comment, or escaping a newline in the middle of a `/*`. Not that I'd recommend writing code like that, but you might want to be aware of it.

```
#define NOT_COMMENT (!DOUBLESLASH_Comment && !ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment)
```

Frankly, I think this looks horrible. A macro that acts like a function should look like a function, not a constant. One of the reasons you're doing this, is that your variable names are too long, so you resort to tricks to keep the line length under control. There's a bit of a relationship between the length of a variable name, and the scope within which it is used: variables used inside a function or a single loop can have shorter names than globals, since the reader doesn't need to remember them for very long.

Helper functions like this are ok, but they need to look like functions to not confuse the reader, and also because you might want to implement them as inline functions. So, make a variable `state`, and a function like `in_comment(state)`. Make `state` a bitfield or a struct if you need.
It might also be good to make test functions like this act in the positive sense, as in `in_comment()`, instead of `not_in_comment()`, just because `! not_in_comment()` may be a bit confusing if it's ever needed.

Though in this case is good to note that you *don't* need two separate variables for the two kinds of comments, since only one type can be active at a time. This shows later in your code, as setting `DOUBLESLASH_Comment` is protected with an `if (NOT_COMMENT)`, etc.

```
if (fopen_s(&input, filename, "r")) {
    perror(filename);
    exit(1);
```

Don't `exit()` from inside a function, just `return` an error code and leave the decision on how to deal with the error to the main program. (Though here, you'd need to close the first file too if the second open fails.) In the same vein, I'd leave the timekeeping to the main program, too.

```
case '\\': {
    if (NOT_COMMENT) {
        if (flag == 1)
            flag = 0;
```

While I don't think variable names need to be especially long, `flag` is much too generic to be of any use (at least without a comment). `escape` perhaps? (Should the backslash also be checked only inside quotes? I'm not sure.)

```
if (NOT_COMMENT && !d_QUOTED) {
    if (!flag)
```

This could be just `if (NOT_COMMENT && !d_QUOTED && !flag)`. Split over two lines if you like. Added confusion since the next almost identical case has the `!s_QUOTED` and `!flag` tests in the opposite order.

Though again, you can only be inside a comment *or* a quoted string, not both, so one variable for those should be enough.

```
case '/': {
    if (NOT_COMMENT && !d_QUOTED)
```

Should this have `&& !s_QUOTED` too?

```
if ((d = getc(input)) == '*') ...
else if (d != EOF) {
        ungetc(d, input);
```

Since the interesting cases need looking ahead to the next character, you might consider pulling the next character in unconditionally at the start of the loop, so you don't need to duplicate the `ungetc` calls in different branches of the function.

```
case '"':  ... d_QUOTED++;
...
if (d_QUOTED == 2) d_QUOTED = 0;
```

I find this logically odd. There's no way to nest quotes, so instead of a incrementing it as a counter, I'd just flip the value when encountering a quote, somewhat like you did with `flag`. So, `d_QUOTED = !d_QUOTED`.

Comment: You can nest a quote by escaping.

Comment: You can put quotes inside quotes by escaping them, yes. But it doesn't result in nesting in the same way parentheses nest. `"'"` is valid even though there is no "ending" single-quote, and so is `"\'"`.

Comment: another thing I would recommend, although it's more of a style review, to not use ALL_CAPS variables unless requried. They seem to scream to look at their definitions since they might be something special or a hack.

Comment: Interesting to know that a backslash escapes a new line even inside a comment. I'll deal with this in my code.

Answer (score 6):

MSalters is right:

> You do know that GCC can already do this? The C preprocessor historically was a separate component, and GCC still can emit the result of preprocessing.

So let's save the comment infested example program from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/comment) as `comments.c`:

```
/* C-style comments can contain
multiple lines */
/* or just one */

// C++-style comments can comment one line

// or, they can
// be strung together

int main()
{
  // The below code won't be run
  // return 1;

  // The below code will be run
  return 0;
}
```

Then, according to the SO question [Can gcc output C code after preprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900870/can-gcc-output-c-code-after-preprocessing), invoke cpp with the `-E` argument like so in terminal:

```
$ cpp -E comments.c
# 1 "comments.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "comments.c"
# 10 "comments.c"
int main()
{




  return 0;
}
```

For prettiness, according to the SO question [How to remove lines added by default by the C preprocessor to the top of the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946898/how-to-remove-lines-added-by-default-by-the-c-preprocessor-to-the-top-of-the-out), add the `-P` argument:

```
$ cpp -E -P comments.c 
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

The cool thing is that the preprocessor is made to be specification compliant. Should they change something about the comments or if there's some wonky way to place a comment in a templated macro contraption inside an XML String literal that's still according to spec but breaks your regex (or whatever you are using), you're screwed. Think of the preprocessor as an executable version of the specification.

Answer (score 3):

Is your code bugged in the following case?

```
printf(" /*This is not a comment but removing me changes program behaviour*/");
```

This one more weird

```
if( match("/*")){
    doMagicStuff();
}
else
    match("*/");
```

You can incurr the risk of it becoming reduced to

```
 if( match(""));  //code that compile fine and have unpredictable side effects
```

You have to write a complete parser (a simple one, but too complex for becoming a single answer) to avoid these issues.

You can know if you have done everything correctly luckily:

- Compile the kernel ==> binaries A
- Strip comments
- Compile the kernel ==> binaries B
- If binaries A and B are not the same, then your comment remover has some bug.

Answer (score 2):

Well done for handling this using a state machine rather than a regular expression.

However, as others have said, you can't get there from here. Your code will always fail in some cases unless you write a full c lexer, so your best approach is to just use a c compiler to do the job for you:

```
gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E file.cpp
```

That said, why *can't* you get there from here?

Because in order to recognize just the scope of double-slash comments and multiline comments, your lexer must also understand backslash-continuations, trigraphs like "??/", different file encodings, and doublequotes. And since it must handle quotes, so it must handle hex, octal, unicode and backslash character escapes. And then you need to handle anything new that gets added in at any point, like "raw string literals" (a C++11 thing like heredocs).

Your code does not currently handle these things. Making it handle these things by writing a full C/C++ lexer would be a good learning experience, but... perhaps more interesting challenges lie elsewhere?

Comment: You're absolutely right.Interesting challenges lie elsewhere,but i wrote that to gain experience.